# Photo Contest Starts Again

Tags: discussion

Community photo contests are happening again :)

[2020 - May - Birds](https://outdoors.codidact.com/questions/74815)

Come join the fun!

Comment: Could we extend this to end of June?   Give people more time to notice there is a new contest and respond.

Comment: @ab2 check the link, there are 11 posts currently. I suspect there will be a different contest next month https://outdoors.codidact.com/questions/74815

Comment: OK -- Problem was I have a new computer which excels at adding an extra step or two to everything.

Answer (score 3):

I was amazed to have missed a photo competition on The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange.
Turns out I did not miss it. It was not on The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange, but run on a different, not connected, site. And 'Should not be mentioned here' as it has nothing to do with Stack Exchange in any way.